# Trying to check if 2 values match in a file

Tags: python, json, file, list

this is a code from a chat bot, and it's purpose is to save into a file all information about an user. That will work fine as long as it's only in 1 room, but if i want to save information of the same user in 2 different rooms, i got a problem. The bot won't just update the information getting the user and the room, instead it will always create new and new lines of that user and that room.

It's getting annoying and i would really like to not break this code a lot, so i'd like to know where it fails and how to fix it in a proper way without using dicts. (You can read all the comments inside the code to understand how i think it works).
Thank you for your time.

```
#First of all it reads the file
leyendoestadisticas = open("listas\Estadisticas.txt", "r")
bufferestadisticas = leyendoestadisticas.read()
leyendoestadisticas.close()
if not '"'+user.name+'"' in bufferestadisticas: #If the name of the user is not there, it adds all the information.
  escribiendoestadisticas = open("listas\Estadisticas.txt", 'a')
  escribiendoestadisticas.write(json.dumps([user.name, palabrasdelafrase, letrasdelafrase,
                                            "1", user.nameColor, user.fontColor, user.fontFace, user.fontSize,
                                            message.body.replace('"', "'"), room.name, 0, "primermensajitodeesapersona", fixedrooms])+"\n")
  escribiendoestadisticas.close()
else: #If the name it's there, it will do the next:
  #First of all, get all rooms where the name is saved, to do that...
  listadesalas = []
  for line in open("listas\Estadisticas.txt", 'r'):
          retrieved3 = json.loads(line)
          if retrieved3[0] == user.name: #If the name is found
            if not retrieved3[9] == room.name: #But room is diferent
              listadesalas.append(retrieved3[9]) #Adds the room to a temporal list
  #Now that we got a list with all different lines of that user based on rooms... we do the next code
  data = []
  hablaenunanuevasala = "no"
  with open('listas\Estadisticas.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
      data_line = json.loads(line)
      if data_line[0] == user.name: #If name is there
        if data_line[9] == room.name: #And the room matches with actual room, then update that line.
          data_line[1] = int(data_line[1])+int(palabrasdelafrase)
          data_line[2] = int(data_line[2])+int(letrasdelafrase)
          data_line[3] = int(data_line[3])+1
          data_line[4] = user.nameColor
          data_line[5] = user.fontColor
          data_line[6] = user.fontFace
          data_line[7] = user.fontSize
          data_line[11] = data_line[8]
          data_line[8] = message.body.replace('"', "'")
          data_line[9] = room.name
          data_line[12] = fixedrooms
        else: #but if the user is there and room NOT matches, we want to add a new line to the file with the same user but a new room.
          if not room.name in listadesalas: #And here is where i believe is the problem of my code.
            hablaenunanuevasala = "si" #needed since i didn't found a way to properly add a new line inside this loop, so must be done outside the loop later.
      data.append(data_line)
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(["%s\n" % json.dumps(i) for i in data])
    f.truncate()
    #Outside the loop - This would work if the program noticed it's a room that is not saved yet in the file for that user.
    if hablaenunanuevasala == "si":
      escribiendoestadisticas2 = open("listas\Estadisticas.txt", 'a')
      escribiendoestadisticas2.write(json.dumps([user.name, palabrasdelafrase, letrasdelafrase,
                                                "1", user.nameColor, user.fontColor, user.fontFace, user.fontSize,
                                                message.body.replace('"', "'"), room.name, 0, "primermensajitodeesapersona", fixedrooms])+"\n")
      escribiendoestadisticas2.close()
```

So... that's what i tried, and it works perfect as long as it's 1 room, it updates the info all the time. When i speak in a second room, it adds me a new record with that second room (perfect). But then if i speak again in ANY of those 2 rooms, the bot will add 2 more lines of code to the file instead of updating the information of the room where i did speak.

**Edit** Let me summarize it:
Let's say I speak in "whenever" room, the file will save a record

```
["saelyth", "whenever", "more info"]
```

If i speak in another room, the file should save a record

```
["saelyth", "anotherroom", "more info"]
```

It works great... but then it doesn't update the info. If now i speak in any of those 2 rooms, instead of updating the proper line, the bot will add more new lines into the file, wich is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda of a personal random project just to learn python, so i didn't though it would matter if i just set names just for me to understand. Now i see this is a problem since they are in spanish and also i need to share the code. - Lesson learned for next time.

Comment: You should isolate your problem to 10 lines of code max, I stared 5 minutes at your code but the spanish variables make it incomprehensible to me.

Comment: Sadly this is the minimum i could isolate it. I'm sure the problem is after the 2nd Else: wich would make the last 15 lines. Nevertheless, that section get info from above and that's why i added it also. Sorry for confusion :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix done... somehow.
I did choose to save info into different files for each room, that works.